# Not able to do http requests within azure function

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I'm testing the new [Azure Function](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-functions/) service.

I've installed the [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) npm library, but it kind of looks like any requests are being blocked some how.

This is my small function:

```
var request = require('request');

module.exports = function(context, req) {
    context.log('function triggered');
    request('http://www.db.no/', function(error, response, body) {
       context.log("inside request callback");
       context.done(); 
    });
};
```

When triggering the function, I get the following logs:

```
2016-06-23T21:59:36  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.
2016-06-23T21:59:39.185 Function started (Id=774d5763-d279-4838-9344-e55a0fcbd858)
2016-06-23T21:59:39.716 function triggered
```

but there it stops. 
[image: function never ends]

The function never ends. The text `inside request callback` never shows up, and the `cancel` button remains enabled.

Are there some limitations here that I don't know about?
Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hmmm, I just tried to repro, and the above code works for me. I get the expected output and the function completes successfully. Can you try again?

Comment: That's strange.
I'll start from scratch and see if things goes differently.

Comment: Wow. Created a new function, installed the npm module, copy-pasted the code: voila! it worked. That's kind of strange, isn't it? The first function still doesn't work...

Comment: I've had one more incident like this one. Solved it the same way: Created new function, copy-pasted code over. Still not able to see any difference between old and new function.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like we may have a change detection bug lurking in there somewhere. We do have a few open issues [in our repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues) related to this. Feel free to open new issue with repro details.

Comment: Bugs do happen. The Azure Function is a fun thing all the same ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for reporting this issue, as Functions was released in [public preview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/announcing-azure-functions-event-driven-compute-on-demand-experience/), at your convenient as long as any further issues encountered please feel free to share your repro at https://github.com/azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues as @mathewc mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a change-detection bug (or you're suspicious that may be the issue), some workarounds:

1. update the log statement that you see is being executed. (context.log('function triggered'); ) . If that still runs the old one, you know for sure this is the problem.
2. Edit the function.json (not just the code).
3. Restart the site from the azure portal. There's a "stop" button in there.